# Can I use incremental, time travel, and snapshot queries with hudi only using spark-sql?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-hudi

I'm trying to do incremental, snapshot, and time travel queries using spark-sql with hudi, but the only way that I can find to do this is creating a DataFrame with spark.read and then creating a temp view.  Is there any way to accomplish this with only using spark-sql?  This is in an EMR cluster, version 6.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

For time travel, you need spark 3.2+:

```sql
select * from <table name> timestamp as of '20221113183401100' where id = 1;
select * from <table name> timestamp as of '2022-11-13 18:34:01.100' where id = 1;
select * from <table name> timestamp as of '2022-11-13' where id = 1;
```

For incremental queries, you need to sync your MoR table to hive, this will create two view for your table, `<table name>_rt` for real-time view, `<table name>_ro` for read-optimized view.

```sql
set hoodie.<table name>.consume.mode=INCREMENTAL;
set hoodie.<table name>.consume.max.commits=3;
set hoodie.<table name>.consume.start.timestamp=20221113183401;
select * from <table name>_rt where `_hoodie_commit_time`>'20221113183401';
```

And for snapshot queries, it is still under development ([issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HUDI-1460)), but you can use the incremental queries syntax to achieve it, by using the timestamp you want to query as start timestamp and setting max commits to 1:

```sql
set hoodie.<table name>.consume.mode=INCREMENTAL;
set hoodie.<table name>.consume.max.commits=1;
set hoodie.<table name>.consume.start.timestamp=20221113183401;
select * from <table name>_rt where `_hoodie_commit_time`='20221113183401';
```